# Textvariable in entry widget does not getting saved in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os
import csv

def cfm():
    root1=Tk()
    txt1=IntVar()
    c1=Entry(root1,textvariable=txt1).grid(row=0,column=0)

    def p1():
        with open('example.csv','w') as c:
            c2=csv.writer(c)
            tnt1 = txt1.get()
            c2.writerow([tnt1])

    b1=Button(root1,text='save',command=p1).grid(row=1,column=0)
    root1.mainloop()

root = Tk()
b1=Button(root,text='submit',command=cfm).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The value of `txt1` is not getting stored in csv file, but there is no error message shown. Why doesn't this code work?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that you're creating two root windows. A tkinter program needs to have a single instance of `Tk`, and you should only ever call `mainloop()` exactly once.

If you need multiple windows, the second and subsequent windows need to be instances of `Toplevel`, not `Tk`.